# What causes html tags to not render in Zend_Element error decorators?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-view, html

I am attempting to insert a link into the error message displayed on a form. in my action I'v done this.

```
    $this->view->editForm->getElement('value')->addError('this type/value combination already exists. click <a href="' 
       . $this->view->url(array(
          'module' => 'collection',
          'controller' => 'tag',
          'action' => 'detail',
          'id' => $tagExists->getId()
       ), null, true) 
   .'">here</a> to load the existing tag');
```

so what I want to see in my web browser when rendered would be

```
this type/value combination already exists click here to load the existing tag
```

and what I'm seeing is

```
this type/value combination already exists click <a href="/collection/tag/detail/id/9">here</a> to load the existing tag
```

i am not sure how to actually cause the link to render correctly in the browser. I'm assuming that there is some sort of output sanitation happening in that error decorator, but I am not sure where I should be looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `escape` option on the *Errors* decorator to `false`.

```
$this->view->editForm->getElement('value')
    ->getDecorator('Errors')->setOption('escape', false);
```

Comment: ok, this throws an error as setEscape() doesn't appear to be a method on that error decorator

Comment: Call to undefined method Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors::setEscape()

Comment: @kristopher right, I was looking at the *Description* decorator. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
$this->view->editForm->getElement('value')
    ->getDecorator('Errors')
    ->setOptions(array('escape' => false));
```

which works